# Make a multiple objects with javascript and png

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to get a spaceship animation scene with a group of comets going down.

```
//Create a comet div with img attached to it
var cometScene = function(spaceNo){
    var b = document.createElement('div');
    b.id = 'cometio';


    var cometImage = document.createElement('img');

    cometImage.setAttribute('src', 'images/comet1.png');
    b.appendChild(cometImage);

    document.getElementById('wrap').appendChild(b);
}

//Comet move
function cometMove(){
    var comet = document.getElementById('cometio');
    var pos = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(scene, 3);

    function scene(){
        if (pos === 1000){
            clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
            pos++;
            comet.style.top = pos + 'px';
            comet.style.left = pos + 'px';
        }
    }

    setInterval(scene, 3)
}
```

But when I call a function cometScene(3) I'm not getting 3 similar objects. Also how these objects can be allocated across the whole screen as this is just a single div.

```
function main(){
    var w = document.createElement('div');
    w.id = 'wrap';

    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(w);
    astronautScene();
    cometScene();
    shaceshipScene();
    cometMove();
    astronautMove();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use IDs more than once (`cometio`), rather give it a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This it what I would do:

1. Give the comets a class instead of an id, because there can be more of them.
2. Because there can be multiple use a loop to iterate through them
3. To give them the ability to move freely, they need to have `position:absolute` or something similiar
4. Don't use the same variable for the position of all comets, because they could be in different positions
5. To get the current position just parse the currect `top` and `left` value to a Number

```js
//Create a comet div with img attached to it
var cometScene = function(spaceNo) {
  var b = document.createElement('div');
  b.className = 'cometio';


  var cometImage = document.createElement('img');

  cometImage.setAttribute('src', 'images/comet1.png');
  b.appendChild(cometImage);

  document.getElementById('wrap').appendChild(b);
}

//Comet move
function cometMove() {
  var comets = document.getElementsByClassName('cometio');
  for (let i = 0; i < comets.length; i++) {
    const comet = comets[i];
    comet.style.top = "0px";
    comet.style.left = "0px";
    comet.style.position = "absolute";
    var interval = setInterval(scene, 3);

    function scene() {
      let x = parseInt(comet.style.left);
      let y = parseInt(comet.style.top);
      if (x === 1000) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      } else {
        comet.style.top = (1 + x) + 'px';
        comet.style.left = (1 + y) + 'px';
      }
    }
  }
  //setInterval(scene, 3)don't start the interval twice
}

function main() {
  var w = document.createElement('div');
  w.id = 'wrap';

  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(w);
  //astronautScene();
  cometScene();
  //shaceshipScene();
  cometMove();
  //astronautMove();
}

main();
```

Comment: The `scene()` is now created for each comet. This is kindof bad, but works. But you should try to move it out of the loop and call it for each element using the same loop inside `scene()`

Comment: Thank you, however I've used a different approach.